# In Google translate page, printing the text area is not working

Tags: watir

I have written the below watir code.

```
b.textarea.set text
```

It's configuring the text within the textarea, but when I attempt to print it, nothing appears. This is because the textarea node itself doesn't contain any text; however, one of the div elements beneath this textarea does. Even when I try to print that specific division using the XPath to locate it, it still doesn't display the expected text. This XPath is used because this particular division is where the text is being set.

```
//textarea/following-sibling::div[2]/div
```

But when I try to print it, it's not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of a textarea, use the `#value` method:

```
b.goto('translate.google.com')
b.textarea.set 'text'
b.textarea.value
#=> "text"
```

If you want to pull text from the following `div`, your XPath does work. However, because the element is not visible and `#text` only returns the visible text, `#text` will return an empty string. You can use `#text_content` to return all of the text nodes regardless of visibility:

```
b.goto('translate.google.com')
b.textarea.set 'text'
b.div(xpath: '//textarea/following-sibling::div[2]/div').text_content
#=> "text"
```

Comment: Amazing, it works. Thanks. `text_content` is the new thing for me.